# How to easily assign values from an object that implements interface A to a variable that implements interface B, where B extends A

Tags: typescript

Assume you have the following interfaces, where `Bar` extends `Foo`

```
interface Foo {
text: string
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
value: number
}
```

Now assume I obtain from somewhere else in the code a variable implementing `interface Foo` named `foo`. Now if I have another variable `bar` that implements `interface Bar` though, and I wish to assign the values from `foo` to `bar`, I get an error -

```
const foo: Foo = { text: '' }
let bar:Bar = foo
Property 'value' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'Bar'.
```

I've managed to work around this by casting all over the place -

```
(bar as Foo) = foo
```

Which I quite frankly find hideously ugly. Is there a way for me to be able to declare the variable, it's type & assign it at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

since `Bar` requires `value`, there is no way to coerce this type without either A using *as Foo* like you are, or B make `value` optional

```
interface Bar extends Foo {
   value?: number
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHKQAeYAXMgM5hSgDmuAvrrqJLIigEJxTISkIIACaU0mHPkIA3OABsArhAD8FEAoC2AI2hMWCdCGrIYmChiwBeHEQHlkAcgfJmciGGRbeZHn2un0IA

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Because all properties from `Bar` are required.

But you can use the utility type **Pick** to do the trick.

```
let bar: Pick<Bar, keyof Foo> = foo
```